# Open new Google Chrome tab in a named window

Tags: linux, command-line, google-chrome, window, command-line-arguments

I'm on Linux and I use scripts to open webpages. I also group my tabs into named Chrome windows, i.e. `--window-name="Group 1"`.

How can I open a new tab in a specifically named window? Testing shows that a new tab opens in the last focused Chrome window.

Comment: It's not currently a Chrome feature - separate windows don't really know about each other anyways. Since you are already naming your Chrome windows, you could set focus with something like `wmctrl` before opening a new tab? For anything more complex, you'd need to use something like Selenium